# 2 android paths equal but drawing performance is different

Tags: android, performance, canvas, path

I have 2 android paths with same actions (moveto, lineto etc...).

when drawing and moving the path 1 its fast. (fps)

when drawing and moving the path 2 its 10-20 times slower. (fps)
I use the same Canvas and the same paint.

What can be the difference?
Are there any properties of a path that influences the performance of drawing?

```
canvas.drawPath(thepath, paint); // FAST
//canvas.drawPath(thepath2, paint); // SLOW
```

Comment: Why a -1. I am asking if there is any property of the path, which influences the behaviour of drawing ?

Comment: Are the path identical or are they different shapes ? drawPath can be faster with simpler shapes, like lots of straight lines and really slow with a lot of jagged stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Going into more detail of android application performance you can use **Systrace** by this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/systrace-commandline.html). Systrace will check and you can easily find out where it takes more time in thepath2.

Comment: You can run on cmd file also, navigate your cmd path to your android sdk and run the command, you will get exact issue. And one more thing once you learn how to use systrace, you can manage your application performance in best way

Comment: Thanks i will try this also for other issues. But I am wondering what can be the difference. If have isolated the problem to only the pathes. So what could be the difference ?

Comment: You can match both processes of drawing paths, and match their trace. You get what runs in background that makes delay in path2

Comment: I can't find the systrace tool in my SDK Folder. I searched the entire SDK-Folder. Where to get this ? Do I have to download something.

Comment: I guess this Android Studio, but I am in Eclipse. I don't know how to start systrace from eclipse ? In DDMS I have a Button "Capture System wide trace using systrace". It produced me a HTML-File of size 280k, which is just emptry white when opening. Also after waiting 1 minute. Am I on the right way ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126523/discussion-between-multidots-solutions-and-mcfly-soft).

Comment: ok thanks a lot. Would be very happy if you can help me in the chat . I am switching to chat now.